# Correlated Subquery with conditional SELECT?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to do something tricky with a correlated sub-query, I need help. I'm using ACCESS to run the query. Here's the data structure:

> TABLE 1----------TABLE 2 REF. NO.---------REF.
>   NO.-----------AMOUNT----------COMPANY----------PRD
>   7897879----------7890849--------------78.15----------------1000----------------BIP
>   **4548694**----------**4548694**---------------13.4-----------------1200---------------OOK 9878945----------**4548694**--------------**210.8**----------------**1300**----------------**IUP**
>   9848987----------1354987---------------120-----------------1500----------------YTE

The REF.NO. in Table 1 doesn't repeat. It ***does*** repeat in Table 2. I wan't to SELECT all the REF.NO.'s from Table 1, and for each of them, bring in the COMPANY and PRD for that REF.NO. from Table 2, where the AMOUNT is the highest. For example, I want a line in my results to look like:

> REF. NO.-----------AMOUNT----------COMPANY----------PRD
>   **4548694**--------------**210.8**----------------**1300**---------------**IUP**

I tried doing something like:

```
(SELECT [TABLE 2].[COMPANY] WHERE [AMOUNT]=MAX([AMOUNT])
```

But that doesn't really make any sense, and the query won't even run. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery.  I'm not sure what `table1` is needed for.  Using just table 2:

```
select t2.*
from table2 as t2
where t2.amount = (select max(tt2.amount)
                   from table2 as tt2
                   where tt2.refno = t2.refno
                  );
```

You can incorporate a filter using `table1` as well, if you need that.

Comment: Thanks! With some minor adjustment to my original query, this worked.